# "una tercera dosis" o "la tercera dosis" o "tercera dosis" (sin artículo)

Tags: gramática, artículos

Pensaba que con los números ordinales deben usarse solamente los artículos definidos. Por supuesto, hay excepciones (ej.: *Carlos quinto*, *feliz tercer mes de lo vuestro*, *seremos primeros de grupo*, *por primera vez*)

Pero encontré unos ejemplos raros para mi donde o se omite el artículo o se usa el artículo indefinido en vez del definido.

En https://www.latercera.com/nacional/noticia/minsal-establece-protocolo-para-que-pacientes-inmunocomprometidos-soliciten-una-tercera-dosis-de-refuerzo-contra-el-covid-19/6AV7NWRCA5B5BK63JT6N5JPHS4/ :

"*Salud formaliza tercera dosis: crea protocolo de inoculación para trasplantados y personas inmunodeprimidas*"

En https://www.elmundo.es/ciencia-y-salud/salud/2021/07/29/6102546fe4d4d8dd088b4570.html :

"*¿Es realmente necesaria **una** tercera dosis de la vacuna de Pfizer contra el Covid?*"

Les agradecería que me explicaran esas diferencias.

Comment: Resulta sorprendente que escriban "Salud formaliza tercera dosis" (que a mi entender es incorrecto) es un medio que se llama, literalmente, **La Tercera**.

Comment: Los titúlos de artículos periodísticos se hacen así. No es redacción en un texto. Es solo el título. Se suele ver mucho.

Comment: @Lambie Parece que no solo de artículos periodísticos, sino de los títulos en YouTube. Aquí https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5_z3mg10Sg

Comment: Si, si. Cualquier título en cualquier mídia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer ejemplo lo considero un error. Quizá es una influencia del inglés, donde se puede omitir el artículo, pero me parece que lo correcto sería

> Salud formaliza una tercera dosis (una nueva dosis)

o también

> Salud formaliza la tercera dosis (que habíamos comentado anteriormente)

Es decir, se puede usar tanto el artículo definido como el indefinido, dependiendo del contexto:

> Conseguí el tercer puesto en la carrera.

> Un tercer puesto en unos juegos olímpicos significa obtener una medalla de bronce.